# Datatables is not passing default parameters in serverSide mode (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

As the title says, i'm having troubles getting the value of the default parameters in serverSide mode in Datatables in CodeIgniter, my Javascript is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_table").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('my_controller/my_method') ?>",
            "type": "POST",
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "some_data" },
            { "data": "some_data" },
        ]
    })
})
```

And when i try to get the default data from the controller's method, it is empty

```
public function my_method()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        $data = $this->input->post();

        var_dump($data);
    }
    else
        redirect('principal', 'refresh');
}
```

I should get the values of 'draw', 'start', 'length', etc. variables but all i get is an empty array. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: test with var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Neither `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: try <script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'</script> in your view , then your  url must be "url": base_url+"'my_controller/my_method'",

Comment: i think site_url() is your defined custom function...

Comment: is there any error in console, did u checked??

Comment: I'm not getting any result even doing it without CodeIgniter.

`devpro` the only error i get is the one that Datatables throws when it doesn't receive properly JSON-parsed data, but i can't process and send the JSON-parsed data if i don't get the default values i'm looking for. =/

Console does not throw any error.

Comment: Guys i already found the mistake, the `serverSide` option is used outside `ajax`.

`"serverSide": true,
 "ajax" : { ... }`

Anyways, thank you very much for your help.